# Start Debugging Item Option Not Showing Up For Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I have a web app `MVC 4.5.1` for `monodevelop`. The `start debugging item` option is no longer showing up. I noticed this happened today after I ran the Ubuntu updates, but not sure if this is related at all.

Is there any way I can get that option back?

EDIT: I also installed Visual Studio Code, which may have done something but also not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out that the add in Mono Soft Debugger Support was disabled, which is weird since I don't recall ever directly modifying it.